# Vue.js emit event from child component not catched

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a child component which fetch some data from my server, before fetching I change the loading status to true and I want to set it to false after the fetch is completed. So I do something like that in my child component:

```
mounted() {
    this.$emit('update:loadingMessage', 'Loading version options from Artifactory...');
    this.$emit('update:isLoading', true);
    this.fetchVersions();
},

methods: {
    fetchVersions() {
        const promises = [
            this.$http.get(`${process.env.API_URL}/version/front`),
            this.$http.get(`${process.env.API_URL}/version/back`),
        ];
        Promise.all(promises)
            .then((values) => {
                // Do some stuff
            })
            .then(() => {
                this.$emit('update:isLoading', false);
            })
            .catch(requestService.handleError.bind(this));
    },
},
```

And in my parent component I listen to this event like that:

```
<version-selector
    :form="form"
    @update:loadingMessage="updateLoadingMessage"
    @update:isLoading="updateLoadingStatus"
    :isSnapshotVersion="isSnapshotVersion">
</version-selector>
```

Finally in the `updateLoadingStatus` I set the `isLoading` value to `true` or `false` accordingly.

```
updateLoadingMessage(message) {
  this.$log.debug(message);
  this.loadingMessage = message;
},
updateLoadingStatus(status) {
  this.$log.debug(status);
  this.isLoading = status;
},
```

This is useful to display or not my `loading` component:

```
<loading
    v-if="isLoading"
    :loadingMessage="loadingMessage"
    :isGiphy="true">
</loading>
```

My problem is that the first emit is working and the `isLoading` value is set to `true` but the second one is not working and my `isLoading` value stay to `true` forever... In my method `updateLoadingStatus` I log the `status` value and I see that this method is just called once.

Comment: Important considerations: First, you're using `this.$emit()` in a `.then()` context. You could be running into issues where `this` is referencing a different context than the Vue instance. Consider doing something like `var this_vue_instance = this;` before entering the `Promise`, then using `this_vue_instance.$emit()` instead. As for your emit capturing issues, I haven't tested this myself, but perhaps the use of the colon in your events is producing issues? I would try eliminating it as a quick test to be sure that it's not conflicting syntax.

Comment: He's using arrow syntax which automatically binds this to the outer scope. The colon in the events wouldn't be an issue because Vue itself actually uses that for it's own events in Vue's `.sync` in one of the recent version. Which version of Vue are you using? Edit: The attribute key having a colon could be an issue.

Comment: `"vue": "^2.5.8"`

Comment: What you're describing is almost the same functionally that `.sync` provides in version `2.3.0` of Vue and later. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier in fact Vue itself uses the @update:key event, which may be the source of your problem.

Comment: I also tried something like that
`v-on:loadingMessage="updateLoadingMessage($event)"`
`v-on:isLoading="updateLoadingStatus($event)"`
and it didn't work neither.

Comment: When using `v-on:isLoading=updateLoadingStatus($event)`, for example, you're actually not going to be capturing the arguments being emitted. To capture these, be sure to do `v-on:isLoading="updateLoadingStatus($event, arguments)"`. You may then access the arguments parameter as an array.

Comment: @B.Fleming According my tests you're wrong when I do that `updateLoadingStatus(event, args) {
      this.$log.debug(event);
      this.$log.debug(args);
      this.isLoading = event;
    },` in the console I have `true` and `undefined`, so there is not 2 parameters. And my real issue is that this function is called once instead of 2 times...

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by using `v-show` instead of `v-if` in my template.

```
<loading
  v-show="isLoading"
  :loadingMessage="loadingMessage"
  :isGiphy="true">
</loading>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I've been struggling with a similar issue since yesterday. I can't understand how a v-if has something to do with this. Did you figure it out by your own or you received an official response from VueJS community? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I stumbled into a similar situation today, and finally understood why the mechanism was working with `v-show`, and not `v-if`.

If you get the following `<template>` tag:

```
<div>
    <component-a v-if="isLoading" />
    <component-b v-else @set-loading-status="setIsLoading" />
</div>
```

And the following `<script>` tag:

```
import ComponentA from './ComponentA'
import ComponentB from './ComponentB'
export default {
    name: 'ParentComponent',
    components: { ComponentA, ComponentB },
    data() {
        return {
            isLoading: false,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setIsLoading(isLoading) {
            this.isLoading = isLoading
        },
    },
}
```

It seems fine, right? You can catch the `set-loading-status` event from the `<component-b>` and set it to `true`. But you can't catch it again to set it back to `false`.

But, let's take a look in the official [Vue docs about `v-if` and `v-show`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show):

> v-if is “real” conditional rendering because it ensures that event listeners and child components inside the conditional block are properly destroyed and re-created during toggles.

Now you can see that the `component-b` gets destroyed when `isLoading` is set to `true`, and you won't be able to catch the emitted event to change it back to `false`.

So, in this particular case, you must use `v-show` to handle the loading status.

Comment: If VueJs v-if handles component destruction and re-creation, shouldn't the framework create the components again with its corresponding events attached? I can't figure out this behaviour with that directive.

Comment: Yes, that's the same idea I had. However, the component that is catching for the event is `component-b`. And when the `isLoading` is set to `true`, that `component-b` is not in the template and is not able to catch the event from the child component simple because it is not there. That's why it works with `v-show`.