# VueJS emit not working in after store dispatch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eventemitter

I'm working with a VueJS component (parent) that has a modal (child) in it. The latter is used to submit data then it should be automatically cleaned and closed and show the results on the parent page.

I use a form inside the modal, when is submitted it dispatches a store action and after that an event is emitted.

If I emit the event before dispatching, it works fine, but if I do it inside the then promise, nothing happens.

*Parent Component*

**Template**

```
<template>
<div>
    <div v-if="this.status !== 'loading'">
        [...]
        <v-dialog 
            v-model="modalAgregarCuenta"
            fullscreen
            hide-overlay
            transition="dialog-bottom-transition">
            <modal-agregar-cuenta 
                ref="modalAgregarCuenta"
                @closeModal="modalAgregarCuenta = false">
            </modal-agregar-cuenta>
        </v-dialog>
        [...]
    </div>
    [...]
</div>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
import ModalAgregarCuenta from './ModalAgregarCuentaBancaria';
[...]

export default {
    components: {
        'modal-agregar-cuenta': ModalAgregarCuenta,
        [...]
    },
    data() {
        return {
            modalAgregarCuenta: false,
            [...]
        }
    },
    watch: {
        [...]
        modalAgregarCuenta(){
            if( this.modalAgregarCuenta )
                this.$store.dispatch(TRACKER_EVENT, { "vm": this, "eventName": 'modal-bank-add-open'});
            else
                this.$store.dispatch(TRACKER_EVENT, { "vm": this, "eventName": 'modal-bank-add-close'});
        }
        [...]
    }
    [...]
}
```

*Child Component*

**Template**

```
<template>
<v-card>
    [...]
    <v-container>
        <v-form ref="formulario" v-model="validation" @submit.prevent="submitForm">
            [...]
        </v-form>
    </v-container>
</v-card>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
    [...]
    methods: {
        submitForm(){
            console.log(this); //<-- Second image
            //this.$emit('closeModal'); //<-- This line works properly

            if(!this.$refs.formulario.validate())
                return;

            this.$store.dispatch(BANK_CREATE_REQUEST, {
                cbu: this.cbu,
                legalNumber: this.accountInformation.legal_number
            })
            .then((res) => {
                this.$emit('closeModal'); //<-- This line does not
                console.log(this); //<-- Third image
                //this.closeModal();
                //this.clear();
                //this.closeModal();
                //this.$emit('closeModal');
                //this.$emit('closeModal');
                /*setTimeout(()=>{
                    //$this.closeModal();
                    this.$emit('closeModal');
                }, 2000);*/
            })
            .catch(err => err);
        },
        closeModal(){
            this.$emit('closeModal');
        },
        clear(){
            this.cbu = '';
            this.legalNumber = '';
        }
    }
    [...]
</script>
```

If I check Vue Devtools, it seems that the event is properly emitted as you can see in the following image:

[image]

I also noticed something weird when I use "console.log" function with "this" before and after dispatching. It's worth noting that the same component is logged in the console but some properties have different values:

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

*UPDATE*

```
[BANK_CREATE_REQUEST]: ({commit}, {cbu, legalNumber}) => {
        commit(BANK_CREATE_REQUEST);
        commit(UI_LOADING, true);
        return apiCall.post(WE_API + '/v3/bank', {
            cbu: cbu,
            legal_number: legalNumber,
            legal_type: null
        })
        .then(res => {
            commit(BANK_CREATE_SUCCESS, res);
            commit(UI_LOADING, false);
            return res;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            commit(BANK_CREATE_ERROR);
            commit(UI_LOADING, false);
            throw err;
        })
    }
    
[BANK_CREATE_REQUEST]: (state) => {
    state.status = 'loading';
},
[BANK_CREATE_SUCCESS]: (state, payload) => {
    state.banks.push(payload.data.model);
    state.status = 'success';
},
[BANK_CREATE_ERROR]: (state) => {
    state.status = 'error';
},
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show your `BANK_CREATE_REQUEST` action. My guess is that you aren't returning a promise or you are returning one that never resolves

Comment: FYI, event names should ideally by kebab-cased, ie `close-modal` instead of `closeModal`. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Comment: Thank you for your adivce with event names, I'll have it in mind. Regarding to the action, I've just updated the question, let me know if you need anything else. Thanks again!!

Comment: Everything looks good (unfortunately). Are you getting any errors? I'd change `.catch(err => err)` to `.catch(err => console.error(err))` but your `BANK_CREATE_ERROR` mutations should already be letting you know if something did go wrong

Comment: I changed the catch clause to log in case of error, but it never reaches there. It seems that "this" is changing when is outside and inside the dispatch. The _events property is different in those two contexts. The problem could be the dispatcher context that is modifying the component context. It is really weird because I could get it working in other pages/components.

Comment: Well, after struggling with this since yesterday, I found a Stack Overflow post with a similar issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47519903/vue-js-emit-event-from-child-component-not-catched). Unfortunately the problem was beyond our scope, it has to do with this line in the parent component "<div v-if="this.status !== 'loading'">". So when I changed v-if for v-show it worked properly. I think that it could be a framework bug or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the content of "this" - i think you won't find any content you'd expect, when you're inside the promise.

This should help you out:

```
let tempThis = this;
...
.then((res) => {
            tempThis.$emit('closeModal'); //<-- This line does work now
```

keep in mind that you could also use async/await (ES6) here, where this "problem" does not occur but you'd have to check the status of the response yourself so it would otherwhise not be that much easier to read or anything